# Count status for items with particular flags at different times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have items which can be flagged with a status for a time range.  In each row, I have the start and stop times for a item with a flag.

For example:

```
start   stop    itemid  flag
1-Jan   1-Feb   1       a
1-Feb   1-Mar   1       b
1-Feb   1-Mar   2       a
1-Jan   1-Mar   3       a
1-Jan   null    4       a
```

What I need is a subcount of a count.  That is, for two dates given (say `1-Jan` and `1-Mar`), I need to count the number of items which had flag `a` at the first date but not flag `a` at the second date. (And other counts, with the other 3 combinations of `a` and not-`a` at those two dates.)

I also need to somehow account for no flag at either date (but not both), but for now I can assume that no flag is `b`.

Essentially, I need to count the following cases: (a,a), (a,b), (a,null), (b,a), (b,b), (b,null); for (x,y), where x is the flag for each item at the first date, and y is the flag at the second date.

Existing, I can count how many flags `a` or `b` exist for a date.

```
select count(1)
from table
where start <= '2014-02-15'
  and (stop >= '2014-02-15' or stop is null)
  and flag = a
```

Comment: Sorry, the question is little confusing, can you add expected output for the above table? Have you checking is Grouping Sets works for you?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the counts.

Notice that I changed your "stop >= '2014-02-15'" to "stop > '2014-02-15'".

You need to decide if the "stop" date is within the interval or not. I'm assuming it's not since you have "1-Feb" on both start and stop for item 1. Otherwise item 1 is in both state a and b on 1-Feb.

```
select sum(case when d1.flag='a' and d2.flag='a' then 1 else 0 end) AA
    ,sum(case when d1.flag='a' and d2.flag='b' then 1 else 0 end) AB
    ,sum(case when d1.flag='a' and d2.flag is null then 1 else 0 end) Anull
    ,sum(case when d1.flag='b' and d2.flag='a' then 1 else 0 end) BA
    ,sum(case when d1.flag='b' and d2.flag='b' then 1 else 0 end) BB
    ,sum(case when d1.flag='b' and d2.flag is null then 1 else 0 end) Bnull
from 
(
    select *
    from table
    where start <= '2014-01-15'
      and (stop > '2014-01-15' or stop is null)
      and flag = 'a'
) d1
left join (
    select *
    from table
    where start <= '2014-02-15'
      and (stop > '2014-02-15' or stop is null)
      and flag = 'a'
) d2 on d1.itemid = d2.itemid
```

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know if there's a different way to do it?  My initial table has about 10 million rows, and the solution seems to take too long.

Comment: Do you have an index on start+stop+flag? That would help.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be better than the other answer. Although it does not use a self-join, it uses grouping twice: explicit grouping in the subselect and implicit grouping in PIVOT. So, at this point, I am offering this solution as just another option for you to try, seeing as the other one did not work well for you, [according to your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274979/count-status-for-items-with-particular-flags-at-different-times#comment37533894_24286067):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    itemid,
    S = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN start <= @d1 AND (@d1 < stop OR stop IS NULL) THEN flag END), '_')
      + ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN start <= @d2 AND (@d2 < stop OR stop IS NULL) THEN flag END), '_')
  FROM @table
  WHERE start <= @d1 AND (@d1 < stop OR stop IS NULL)
     OR start <= @d2 AND (@d2 < stop OR stop IS NULL)
  GROUP BY
    itemid
) AS s
PIVOT (COUNT(itemid) FOR S IN (aa, ab, a_, ba, bb, b_)) AS p
;
```

The `@d1` and `@d2` are your dates parametrised.

The subselect finds `itemid`s that have data matching at least one of the date arguments, then determines which status each `itemid` had on either date, marking the absence of a status with an underscore. It then combines the two statuses into a single string value, returned as column `S`. So, if there was status `'a'` on the first date and same status on the other, the resulting string would be `'aa'`, and if, for another example, the first one was `'b'` and there was no data for the second date, the `S` would be `'b_'`, and so on.

The resulting set is then pivoted and aggregated, the `S` column providing column names for the pivoted results. Note that the derived table could also potentially return strings `'_a'` and `'_b'`. If you decided to include them into the PIVOT column list, you might get non-zero results for them too.